# unusual timeout trouble with sftp and Filezilla

Tags: openshift

**Anyone else having sftp problems?**

I have used Filezilla and sftp to 2 Openshift sites for over 2 years without a problem from Win & Linux.

Yesterday and today I could not connect to one site (using Filezilla on Windows or Ubuntu).
Other parts of the account worked normally, eg phpmyadmin and the website.

If I used ssh on Ubuntu it would connect in 130, 24 or 22 seconds.

Changing the timeout in Filezilla to 180 seconds did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

**Work around**

The work around for me was to swap from using the domain name for sftp back to the original rhcloud.com alias.

Now Filezilla with sftp works normally again.